# How to get change list details for provided users with specified date?

Tags: perforce

I need to collect `Perforce Change List details` for `provided users` and with provided `date - (ie... from 01-06-22 to 25-12-22)` in csv format.

**Expected output in csv per Change List:-**

| S.No | Perforce Username | Change List | Submitted Date | Workspace | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dary.spitzer | 123456 | 02-08-2022 | Daryl_Spitzer_Workspace | Fixed alarm issues |
| 2 | shadkam.san | 78910 | 24-12-2022 | Shadkam_san_Workspace | PostgreSQL Support added |

Thank you very much for reading and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `p4 changes` with the `-u` flag to specify the user and the dates given as a revision range argument:

```
C:\Perforce\workshop>p4 changes -u samwise @2009/01/01,2010/01/01
Change 7479 on 2009/11/12 by samwise@samwise-silver 'Fix typo in last change. '
Change 7113 on 2009/01/22 by samwise@samwise-silver 'Make VSStoP4 html page a redire'
```

To reformat this into something resembling a CSV at the CLI you could use the `-F` flag:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %user%,%change%,%client%,%desc% changes -u samwise @2009/01/01,2010/01/01
samwise,7479,samwise-silver,Fix typo in last change.

samwise,7113,samwise-silver,Make VSStoP4 html page a redire
```

I would personally use Python rather than Bash to finish massaging this into the desired form though:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import sys
from P4 import P4

out = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
out.writerow([
    "S.No",
    "Perforce Username",
    "Change List",
    "Submitted Date",
    "Workspace",
    "Description"
])
my_users = {'samwise'}

with P4().connect() as p4:
    for i, change in enumerate(p4.run_changes('@2009/01/01,2010/01/01'), 1):
        if change['user'] not in my_users:
            # This makes it easy to handle multiple users
            continue
        out.writerow([
            i,
            change['user'],
            change['change'],
            datetime.fromtimestamp(int(change['time'])).date(),
            change['client'],
            change['desc'].strip()
        ])
```

produces:

```
S.No,Perforce Username,Change List,Submitted Date,Workspace,Description
1,samwise,7479,2009-11-12,samwise-silver,Fix typo in last change.
2,samwise,7113,2009-01-22,samwise-silver,Make VSStoP4 html page a redire
```

Comment: Not in one command; you'd want to run the command twice with different user args, put it all in a list, and sort by change number before writing out the CSV.  If you have a lot of users, I'd just run it without the user filter and do the filtering in the script instead of in the command (`if change['user'] not in my_users` or whatever) .